# Не работает функция addEventListener

Tags: javascript

```js
let button1 = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
let name = document.getElementsByClassName('name1'),
  date = document.getElementsByClassName('date');


button1.addEventListener('click', function() {
  date.value = name.textContent;
});
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <input class="information-item date" type="text" placeholder="Here" maxlength="25">
  <button class="information-item-btn" id="save1">OK</button>
</div>

<div class="box-code" <div class="name1">1. Here: </div>
<div class="result-value"></div>
</div>
```

С текстового окна не переносится в Див, в чем проблема?)

Comment: Так вы же по логике кода наоборот, с дива в окно переносите

Comment: Невнимательность)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let button1 = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
let name = document.getElementsByClassName('name1')[0],
  date = document.getElementsByClassName('date')[0];

button1.addEventListener('click', function() {
  name.textContent = date.value;
});
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <input class="information-item date" type="text" placeholder="Here" maxlength="25" value="test">
  <button class="information-item-btn" id="save1">OK</button>
</div>

<div class="box-code">
  <div class="name1">1. Here: </div>
  <div class="result-value"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Gover123 Поменяйте их местами.

Comment: Извините за тупость, все верно, спасибо.

Comment: @Gover123 Ничего, пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Comment: через 4м смогу только))